# How to add more names in Baby Name Page?

Tags: import

I have created Page of Baby Name and added some names of baby with customs fields of Name Meaning and Religion. 
[image]
[image]
[image]
Please help me How can I add more names through importing from CSV or excel file ? 
Thank you.